# Dom Modification to clear Radio Button Info with Reset Button

Tags: javascript, dom

So I have made a form that I can clear with a reset button. On this form, I have four radio buttons (that code is towards the top). When a button is selected, info comes up using "displayText".

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function textToDisplay (radioValue) {
console.log("textToDisplay + " + radioValue);
var displayText = "";
if (radioValue == "S") {
  displayText = "Shortboards are under 7 ft in length.";
}
else if (radioValue == "L") {
  displayText = "Longboards are usually between 8 and 10 ft.";
}
if (radioValue == "A") {
  displayText = "Alternative boards defy easy aesthetic description.";
}
if (radioValue == "M") {
  displayText = "Mid-Length surfboards are between 7 and 8 ft.";
}
return (displayText)
}

//DOM modification
function modifyDom(radioInput) {
console.log(radioInput.name + " + " + radioInput.value);
var displayText = textToDisplay(radioInput.value);
console.log(node);
var insertnode = document.getElementById("radioButtons");
var infonode = document.getElementById("info")
if (infonode === null) {
  console.log("infonode does not yet exist");
  var node = document.createElement("DIV");
  node.setAttribute("id", "info");
  node.className = "form-text infoText";
  var textnode = document.createTextNode(displayText);
  node.appendChild(textnode);
  console.log(node);
  insertnode.appendChild(node);
}
else {
  console.log("infonode already exists");
  infonode.innerHTML = displayText;
}
}
function checkboxesSelected (checkboxes, errorString) {
console.log("checkboxesSelected function");
var cbSelected = 0;
for (i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++) {
  if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
    cbSelected += 1;
  }
}
if (cbSelected < 2) {
  return (errorString);
} else {
  return "";
}
}
function validate (form) {
console.log("validate form");
var fail = "";
fail += checkboxesSelected(form.extras, "At least TWO fin setup needs 
to be selected.\n")
if (fail == "") return true
else { alert(fail); return false }
}
</script>
```

When I reset my page using the button,

```
  <input type="reset" name="reset" value="Reset">
```

the buttons themselves are cleared but the information that appeared from selecting the button is still visible. How can I reset the page so the displayText information is not visible? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to information technologies and I'm still learning. I changed it!

Comment: Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: With "When I reset my page", do you mean having a `reset` button on your form and pressing that? Could you provide more of your code, please? Especially where you call `textToDisplay` might make your intentions a bit clearer for me

Comment: Yes, I've added more code, probably too much of it. I'm still learning about how this code functions. Thanks,

Comment: Could we have your full form please Kyle? As in, the rest of the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an event listener for the [reset event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/reset) generated by clicking the reset button to execute cleanup code.

Here's a *cut down example* of the technique:

```js
"use strict";
let myForm = document.getElementById("myForm");
let infoNode = document.getElementById("infonode");
let infoText = {
  "S": "small board's are good",
  "L": "large board's are good too"
};

myForm.addEventListener("change", function (event) {
  if(event.target.name == "size") {
    infoNode.innerHTML = infoText[ event.target.value];
  }
}, false);

myForm.addEventListener("reset", function (event) {
  infoNode.innerHTML  = "";
}, false);
```

```html
<form id="myForm">
  <label> <input name="size" type="radio" value = "S"> Short</label><br>
  <label> <input name="size" type="radio" value = "L"> Long</label><br>
  <input type="reset" value="reset">
</form>
<div id="infonode"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

would suggest to remove the dynamically attached `div#info`:

```
document.getElementById("info").remove();
```

or blank it:

```
document.getElementById("info").innerHTML = "";
```

Comment: `modifyDom()` explicitly checks if  a div with id "info" exists to reuse it if possible. How, when and where to blank the div's content is actually the question!

Comment: @traktor53 have seen that... that's why I've provided both alternatives. the actual question is, why the question does not feature the `HTML` markup of the form? there might even be ways to blank the whole form at once.

Comment: I'm currently trying to add the rest of the HTML, thanks for the comments I really appreciate it.